# Airflow - where to place Dataset definition

Tags: python, airflow, git-submodules

We are using the official airflow helm chart and deployed it to kubernetes, our setup uses `KubernetesExecutor` and `git-sync`. We use one core git repository as a default location for DAGs. Every project gets its own git repository, which is then added as a git submodule to the core repo.
With this setup in mind, where do you place an airflow `Dataset` to be able to run data-aware scheduling, if the Datasets are shared across the projects? For example, `projectA` and `projectB` both use the same `Dataset`, where do I code the definition?
I had a couple of ideas, but each of them has a drawback:

- module inside the core repo - now I would have to include the core repo in every project CI/CD pipeline, because we test each project independently
- module inside each project's repo - a lot of copy pasting, not convinced this is the best idea
- separate python package - not sure if this would work, I am concerned whether airflow can pick up the Datasets seamlessly. Also how to handle cases if one project has different version of the package than others?
- git submodule added to each repo - again the concern about different checked out commits is present

Not really sure what the best course of action is here, any feedback is appreciated!

Comment: I don't understand your need. As long as the dataset producer(s) and consumer(s) are in the same Airflow instance, we're just talking about a configuration string ? Do you want to use a shared python object between git submodules ? Then this question does not relate to airflow.